# How to recover Netbeans main() logs?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I ran a process directly in Netbeans using Main().
The process run for 2 days.
After that i mistakenly rerun the process and all my logs for last two days washed away.

I am trying to find the same. Could anyone suggest where should it be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a bit like you printed something via println which is displayed in the ouput-window and you refer to this output as a log.

If you are not using a logger which explicitly logs into a file you are out of luck. Then your output is gone and you need to re-run your program. Netbeans itself is not persisting the output anywhere. But before you re-run your program you should definitely use a logger (e.g. log4j2) which logs into a file.